Why are there 2 image files being rendered when my html and js have one image.jpg
Why are there 2 image files being rendered when my html and js have one image.jpg.
I'm using static Html with CSS and JSS and Webpack.
see image below:

The code is in Github here:  https://github.com/kevindRuby/hello-webpack-eg1
Preferred outcome: For the image to display once on top of blinking text.
Code main.js:
    import imageSrc from './image.jpg'; // Adjust the path if necessary

const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
imgElement.src = imageSrc;
imgElement.alt = 'Description of image';
document.body.appendChild(imgElement);


const textElement = document.createElement('h1');
textElement.textContent = 'This text will blink!';
document.body.appendChild(textElement);

setInterval(() => {
    textElement.style.visibility = (textElement.style.visibility === 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden');
}, 500);

Solution::
main.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello Webpack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

main.js
import imageSrc from './image.jpg'; // Webpack will handle this

// Remove any existing images dynamically before adding a new one
const existingImage = document.querySelector('img');
if (existingImage) {
    existingImage.remove();
}

// Dynamically create the image element and add it to the DOM
const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
imgElement.src = imageSrc;  // This will point to the processed image URL
imgElement.alt = 'Description of image';
document.body.appendChild(imgElement);

// Make the text blink
const textElement = document.createElement('h1');
textElement.textContent = 'This text will blink!';
document.body.appendChild(textElement);

setInterval(() => {
    textElement.style.visibility = (textElement.style.visibility === 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden');
}, 500);


You'll need to post your code here for assistance. Links aren't permanent over time, leaving out help for future developers.

Add code for assistance. Makes it convenient to others

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please add your current code here. As soon as you push any changes to the repo the question will likely be invalidated and not helpful for someone else with a similar issue.

code added for main.js

In main.html, you explicitly create the image, right after the header.
You then call your main.js script directly after, where  you call the .appendChild() function on the body to create a second image.
I don't understand what you mean by "display once on top of blinking text", however you can get rid of the second image by removing the first 5 (6 including the blank) lines of code in your main.js file

You have in your main.js file
import imageSrc from './image.jpg'; // Adjust the path if necessary

const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
imgElement.src = imageSrc;
imgElement.alt = 'Description of image';
document.body.appendChild(imgElement);

